# Is it possible to draw a animated logo or spiral in python without using turtle?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, animation

[image]I want to draw a animated plot or logo using python code but without using turtle. Possibly using other packages for animating the segments of the plot. Can you help me to animate the following image?

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


RADIUS = 100

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.penup()  # we'll use fill instead of lines
turtle.color(20, 191, 150)  # greenish color

turtle.sety(-RADIUS)  # center hexagon
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(RADIUS, steps=6)  # draw hexagon
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.color('white')  # interior color
turtle.sety(2 * RADIUS / 11)  # position circle (head)
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(2 * RADIUS / 9)  # draw circle (head)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.forward(5 * RADIUS / 8)
turtle.right(85)

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 190)
turtle.right(85)
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 90)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.circle(-13 * RADIUS / 20, 90)
turtle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

the above code courtesy @cdlane

Comment: So you are asking for references to other libraries? I suggest PIL/Pillow

Comment: can you help me to animate the given image using the PIL package...